# Upstart job does not trigger (Xubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, xubuntu

I'm in the process of learning how to use Upstart. I wrote a simple job as a test (file is `/etc/init/uptest.conf`), using a custom event to trigger it manually:

```
start on uptest
task
exec touch /tmp/UPTEST
```

This works fine on a server running Ubuntu 14.04.2, by calling

```
# initctl emit uptest
```

My problem is that the exact same job does not work on a Xubuntu 14.04 install. the Upstart version is 1.12.1 on both machines.

I have been unable to point out the cause so far:

- syntax of the conf file is ok, as shown by the `init-checkconf` command
- calling `initctl start uptest` displays: "initctl: Unknown job: uptest"
- indeed this job is not listed in `initctl list`
- I tried to reload (`initctl reload-configuration`) and reboot, without success
- I can't find any useful log in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/upstart`

I'm running out of ideas... maybe someone here will have a clue ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the same filename in the xubuntu system?

Comment: @Braiam - yes, I also did check the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the session init is being called to instead of the system init. Try it by unsetting the variable `UPSTART_SESSION`

```
env -u UPSTART_SESSION initctl list
env -u UPSTART_SESSION initctl start uptest
```

etc.